# C++, one block of memory vs multiple

Tags: c++, class

I am new to C++ and wanted to create a class for matrix and found two methods:

1. allocating one block of memory (which is faster as I read)
2. allocating multiple blocks (one for each line which is slower)

But what is better?
on the one hand I can use the second like mat[i][j] which doesn't work with the first method.
and I need to write a function that multiplies matrixes and I'm afraid that the first method will make things really hard when trying to access members

Comment: While the first method introduces some more complexity to the code, it should be an order of magnitudes faster.  If you want to see how it can be implemented, see: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/155811/basic-matrix-class-in-c

Comment: "what is better" depends entirely on what your definition of "better" is. This seems a bit too broad as currently written. "_on the one hand I can use the second like mat[i][j] which doesn't work with the first method_" - so just provide an `operator()(i, j)` that does the multi-dimensional indexing (and then wait for C++23 or later to support multi-dim indexing natively in `operator[]`).

Answer (score 0):

Where did you read that? 2-dimensional matrix can be represented both as a 1-dimensional array or 2-dimensional array. It's just a matter of references with 2 index. So for an element of having index `row` and `col` you can get its 1-dimensional index like this: `row * matrix_width + col`. So there's no impact on the speed besides calculating this index formula.

Comment: They meant that in the other scenario, each row would be an independently allocated array. That's obviously not necessary but _is_ possible. However, it's going to hurt performance (at least during allocation), caching, etc.

Comment: @underscore_d so can I implement it as one block of memory and still has [i][j] possible? please show an example

Comment: https://www.hellgeeks.com/two-dimensional-arrays/ read this for some examples.

Comment: @clark_smith Hack06 gave an example. You just define an `operator()(i, j)` or even just a `get_cell(i, j)` and multiply `row * width + col` to get the '2D' location in the backing 1D array.